# NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary : which is best for this scenario?

Tags: ios

I need to scroll through several thousands of words to categorize them... to determine which words have the same pattern. (this part works)
For example, a four letter word that has two m's in 2nd & 4th position represent a pattern ("-m-m").  Once I have gone through all the words, I will know how many words there are for any given pattern.  I am scrolling through now, but the problem I have is 'remembering' how many words I have in any given pattern.

I was thinking of using NSMutableDictionary and have the key be the pattern ('-m-m-') and the object represent the count of that pattern.  This means every time I come across a pattern, I look up that pattern in the dictionary, get the key, increment the key, and put it back in the dictionary.

I need help with both the decision and syntax for performing this task.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question was this part of your (given) question "I will know how many words there are for any given pattern.".  I would use an array of dictionary.  You use the dictionary to store key value pair: a known pattern and the count.  And you use the array to store those KVP records.  So the next time you detect a pattern, search for the array for that record (dictionary), if found, increment the count.  If not, create new record and set the count to 1.

Added sample code:

```
#define kPattern @"Pattern"
#define kPatternCount @"PatternCount"

-(NSMutableDictionary *)createANewDictionaryRecord:(NSString *) newPattern
{
    int count = 1;
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   newPattern, kPattern,
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count], kPatternCount,
                                   nil];
    return myDictionary;
}

-(void)addANewPatternToArray:(NSMutableDictionary *)newDictionary
{
   // NSMutableArray *myArrayOfDictionary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  // you need to define it somewhere else and use property etc.
    [self.myArrayOfDictionary addObject:newDictionary];  //or [self.myArrayOfDictionary addObject:newDictionary];  if you follow the recommendation above.
}

-(BOOL)existingPatternLookup:(NSString *)pattern
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *obj in self.myArrayOfDictionary)
    {
        if ([[obj objectForKey:kPattern] isEqual:pattern])
        {
            int count = [[obj objectForKey:kPatternCount] intValue] + 1;
            [obj setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count] forKey:kPatternCount];
            return YES;
        } 
    }
    [self.myArrayOfDictionary addObject:[self createANewDictionaryRecord:pattern]];
    return NO;
}

-(void)testData
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [self createANewDictionaryRecord:@"mmm"];
    [self addANewPatternToArray:newDict];
}

-(void) printArray
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary * obj in self.myArrayOfDictionary)
    {
        NSLog(@"mydictionary: %@", obj);
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    if ([self existingPatternLookup:@"abc"])
    {
        [self printArray];
    } else 
    {
        [self printArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You.  Do you have a snippet of how this might be implemented?  I like this approach but am struggling with syntax.

Comment: I added a complete sample code.... see if it helps.  btw: The code is by no means optimized!

Comment: Edit to move the addOject outside the for loop in the existingPatternLookup.

Comment: @user523234 +1! Good answer...it's time you chose your username, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Not being an objective C expert but solving this problem in java before, I would say a dictionary(I used a map when doing it in java) is the best way.  Check if the key(pattern) already exist if so increment that count else put a new one in the dictionary.

**EDIT**

If you want to not just get the count of a pattern, but in fact tell which words fall under that pattern, I would use a dictionary of strings to mutable arrays.  In the arrays you store the words and the key to the array is the pattern(as a string), similar code as above but instead of just incrementing the count, you have to add the new word to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary is that one can have objects added to it.  I think your implementation is good, but English is a complex language.  It would be more efficient to parse out the string with regex than to set a key for it.

Comment: Uh, I think the question is about arrays and dictionaries, not mutable and immutable dictionaries.

Comment: @Chuck, i get the sinking feeling you didn't fully read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `NSCountedSet` instead:

[NSCountedSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCountedSet%22)

..which is available in iOS 2.0 and later?

> Each distinct object inserted into an NSCountedSet object has a counter associated with it. NSCountedSetkeeps track of the number of times objects are inserted [...] Thus, there is only one instance of an object in an NSSet object even if the object has been added to the set multiple times. The count method defined by the superclass NSSet has special significance; it returns the number of distinct objects, not the total number of times objects are represented in the set.

Then use:

```
- (NSUInteger)countForObject:(id)anObject
```

Comment: NSCountedSet doesn't exist on iOS, which is what this post is tagged with.

Comment: @thebarcodeproject according to Apple, it is available on iOS 2.0 and later. Before commenting and downvoting, would you mind checking the docs? Thank you.

Comment: I apologise and I tried to upvote it to undo my down vote, however it did not allow it. If you were the one who downvoted me just because I downvoted you, that's pretty bad form...

Comment: @thebarcodeproject I think that you click on the downvote again to undo it.

Comment: I tried that. Tells me that I cannot unvote as it was too long ago and cannot change it unless magma edits his post.

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary of NSMutableArrays, and check for the existence of each search key as you recommended. If the key doesn't exist, add an NSMutableSet or NSMutableArray (depending on your needs) for the searched key type "-m-m" for example, and then add to the set or array for that key.